# Reliable web application GUI testing

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I'm currently using [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) for testing our web application's interface. However, it isn't very reliable (it's hard to set a good waiting timeout, absolutely a nightmare to work with in any webpages involving frames) and lacks many features (popups/downloads).

I took a look at http://sikuli.csail.mit.edu/ and quite like it, but again, it isn't very reliable as in very often it fails to identify the correct buttons/links.

What is a good approach for testing web applications?

PS: I'm after the ones that would allow for testing even if the tester has ZERO knowledge about the internal of the codes (not even the method signatures).

Comment: http://sikuli.csail.mit.edu/ seems to be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, UI testing is not very reliable in general. Having to use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), because IDs aren't set on elements on the page. Having to use frames (I hate frames and glad its being deprecated in [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)).

It's the nature of the beast unfortunately and a major issue I find with Selenium, which is my prefered UI testing tool for browsers, is that people start on the Selenium IDE which tries to record everything you do, but it can only do so much making tests unreliable.

Record/Replay tools should be called Record/Tweak/Replay, so that it can handle tests correctly.

Writing your tests for Selenium RC or WebDriver (these are currently being merged to create Selenium 2) allows you to handle the issues that you may see in Selenium IDE. It makes you write tests using programming languages like Java, Python, C# and many more. Since you can add conditionals to your tests.

The way that I have got less technical people to use Selenium is to create a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for them to use, so that it is a more natural language when writing tests.

Comment: I think that Selenium is basically leading edge of automated UI testing. If it's not good enough, there's not really much that's better.

Comment: I am not sure the WebDriver guys would see it as leading edge but once the 2 projects have been fully merged it will be the best tool out there by miles in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in).

1. It does not need to wait for [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) or page loads.
2. It does not use XPaths, using [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) relations (_near, _in) instead.
3. It traverses frames/iframes automatically
4. The recorder works for frames, iframes, and popup windows
5. It handles auto generated IDs well
6. The recorder and playback works on almost all browsers and operating systems.
7. It does not use special privileges to run tests.

Over the last year, Sahi has had seven public releases and the support is prompt on the forums.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Sahi.

Comment: I am 'evaluating' Sahi at the moment, and I can tell you that lack of need for waitForPageToLoad and/or waitForElementPresent is a Godsend! To me, that is one of the best parts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");` use like this

> selenium.waitForPageToLoad(Timeout);

and don't forget to set the timeout using settimeout option

> selenium.setTimeout(Timeout);

I too faced the same issues with the timeout. After setting the timeout, things worked well.